# Third party Microsoft software installation troubles

Tags: apt

A tried to install codecs, drivers etc after installing Ubuntu, via

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

But it completely crashed and broke package system i had to repair. Cause was proprietar Microsoft fonts. There appeared MS EULA which was impossible to confirm. There was no working "button".

What can i do?
Could i exclude this particular proprietar MS package from installing?

Comment: It's an `ncurses` dialog, which requires you to accept using keyboard (you cannot use mouse). Use arrow, tab key & enter.

Comment: You can install `install ubuntu-restricted-addons` instead.